# Using page factory class inside a constructor in page object model framework

Tags: selenium

I have been using the page object model framework with testing for running our automated tests and are using the page factory class for initializing the web elements of a page object. To initialize the web elements of a class I use the following statement in my page object constructor - objectname = PageFactory.initElements(driver, Page.class); Along with this piece of code, I also have another statement to initialize my driver inside the constructor. Something like driver = new firefoxdriver(); I know that this is not the correct way to do things but when I execute tests that have a call to this page my browser keeps opening again and again. However when I use this method - PageFactory.initElements(driver, this); this problem does not happen and my tests execute fine. Can someone explain how the function PageFactory.initElements(driver, Page.class); exactly works and why I am seeing what I see?

Here is my code

```
public class SNMPPage {

    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SNMPPage.class);

    WebDriver driver;

    public SNMPPage(){
        this.driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, SNMPPage.class);
    }
}

public class SNMP_Validations {

static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SNMP_Validations.class);

SNMPPage snmpPage;

     @BeforeClass
     public void Initialize_Page_Elements() throws Exception{
            ExcelUtils.setExcelFile(Constants.excelLocation, "SNMP Page");
            snmpPage = new SNMPPage();
     }
    @Test`public void Verify_If_Enable_SNMP_Checkbox_Is_Selectable(){`
    log.info("Verifying if enable checkbox in the SNMP page is selectable");
        ExtentTestManager.getTest().log(Status.INFO,"Verifying if enable checkbox in the SNMP page is selectable" );
        snmpPage.clickSnmpOptionInMainMenu();
        Assert.assertEquals(snmpPage.checkIfEnableCheckboxIsSelectable(), true, "SNMP enable checkbox is not selectable");
        log.info("SNMP enable checkbox is selectable");
        ExtentTestManager.getTest().log(Status.INFO,"SNMP enable checkbox is selectable" );

   }

@Test public void Verify_Error_Message_On_Submitting_System_Info_With_An_Empty_System_Name(){
log.info("Verifying if an error message is displayed when the user submits system info with an empty system name");
        ExtentTestManager.getTest().log(Status.INFO,"Verifying if an error message is displayed when the user submits system info with an empty system name" );
        snmpPage.clearSystemNameTextBox();
        snmpPage.clickSaveButton();
        Assert.assertEquals(snmpPage.verifyErrorMessageOnEmptySystemName(), true, "Error message not displayed when the user submits system info with an empty system name");
        log.info("Error message displayed when the user submits system info with an empty system name");
        ExtentTestManager.getTest().log(Status.INFO,"Error message displayed when the user submits system info with an empty system name" );
}
```

Comment: We can't help you without the code. The actual code, not a description of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Irrespective of where you are putting it, following is what happens:

`this.driver = new FirefoxDriver();`

Everytime this line is executed, you will cause selenium to open up a new browser window. If you are having this line within your constructor, then a browser opens up every time you create an object of your class ( `SNMPPage` in your case )

When you do `PageFactory.initElements(driver, SNMPPage.class);`

The following things happen:

- The class `SNMPPage.class` is loaded and using reflection a check is done to find a constructor which takes in a `WebDriver` as a parameter. If that constructor is found, then it is used to instantiate the object. If that constructor is NOT found, then the default constructor is invoked and an object of type `SNMPPage` is eventually returned after the next below steps are executed.
- Selenium uses reflection to initialise the newly created page object. When I say initialisation, I am basically referring to the following:

  - For every class, its public, private and protected fields are extracted out.
  - For every such field the decorator spurts out proxy object values, which is then injected into the field map of the page object.
  - If the field is a WebElement then a proxy which uses an instance of LocatingElementHandler is created and used.
  - If the field is a List of WebElements then a proxy which uses an instance of LocatingElementListHandler is created and used.

Long story short:
If you are trying to initialise yourself within a constructor of your page object, then do it as below:

```java
public SNMPPage() {
        this.driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }
}
```

If you are doing this from outside of your page object then you can very well do the following:

```java
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
SNMPPage snmPPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, SNMPPage.class);
```

I have explained the complete working of Page factory in my blog [here](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2016/09/05/understanding-pagefactory/). You can refer to it for more details.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time out and answering this in detail Krishnan Mahadevan. As you said this.driver = new FirefoxDriver(); opens up a new browser window every time i create an object of SNMP class. I have added more code to my question above and by referring to it you can see that I create an object just once in my @Before Class method and then use it to invoke all my validations from the page object class. So how is it that the browser gets invoked every time even though I have created my object just once?

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance if my understanding about this is incorrect. I am relatively new to this. Thank you once again :)

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a good idea to create a driver factory and every time to call it when you access webdriver.
And make sure that once the driver is initialized you will get the instance and not creating a new one.

Comment: I am aware that creating a driver factory is in my best interests but I was just curious as to why this is happening. Maybe i do not understand the init Elements function properly.

Comment: Each time when you initialize a page you a creating a new instance of webdriver:
this.driver = new FirefoxDriver();

Comment: Is my understanding wrong that the statement  PageFactory.initElements(driver, SNMPPage.class); is executed only once inside the constructor? What do you exatly mean by "each time initialize a page" ?

Comment: In the constructor of the page, you are creating a new instance of Webdriver. That is why each time when you create a page object a new browser window is open.
Create a Webdriver Factory where you create one instance of the object and each time when you create a page object get the existing instance of Webdriver object.